# Solution to Binary Tree Max Height in one direction

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree

I was set a problem which I attempted to solve. The problem required finding the maximum height *in one direction* of a binary tree. E.G. if a branch continued leftwards, then the height continues to increase, but if the branch then went right, the height would be reset to 1.

I came up with the following in C#, which I am not even sure if it's correct.

Does anyone know the optimal solution?

```
 class MaxHeightInOneDirection
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Tree a = new Tree();
        a.x= 20;

        Tree b = new Tree();
        b.x = 21;

        Tree c = new Tree();
        c.x = 12;
        c.l = b;
        c.r = a;

        Tree d = new Tree();
        d.x = 10;
        d.l = c;

        Tree e = new Tree();
        e.x = 3;

        Tree f = new Tree();
        f.x = 5;
        f.l = e;
        f.r = d;

        int maxHeight = GetHeight(f)[2];

    }

    public int[] GetHeight(Tree root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            return new int[]{-1,-1, 0};

        int[] leftResult = GetHeight(root.l);
        int[] rightResult = GetHeight(root.r);

        // Increase left on current left
        leftResult[0]++;
        // Set right result on current left to 0
        leftResult[1] = 0;
        // Set left result on current right to 0
        rightResult[0] = 0;
        // Increase right on current right
        rightResult[1]++;

        int leftMaxSoFar = leftResult[2];
        int rightMaxSoFar = rightResult[2];

        int maxValueSoFar = Math.Max(leftMaxSoFar, leftResult[0]);
        maxValueSoFar = Math.Max(maxValueSoFar, rightResult[1]);
        maxValueSoFar = Math.Max(maxValueSoFar, rightMaxSoFar);

        return new int[] { leftResult[0], rightResult[1], maxValueSoFar };
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What goes wrong? Use the debugger. set breakpoints. Watch your variables. Compare expected values to actual values.

Comment: For what it's worth, at a glance I think your algorithm is correct and that there's not much you could do to optimise it, although I think the `xResult[1] = 0;` assignments are at best unnecessary and at worst confusing.

Comment: DrKoch - There is nothing incorrect with the solution as far as I'm aware; I'm just looking for a neater solution if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

To find height of tree you can simply use this algo :-[here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-find-the-maximum-depth-or-height-of-a-tree/)

in c# do something

```
int MaxDepth(Tree node) 
{
   if (node==NULL) 
       return 0;
   else
   {      
       int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);
       int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);

       /* use the larger one */
       if (lDepth > rDepth) 
           return(lDepth+1);
       else return(rDepth+1);
   }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want the height of the tree.